# EF Core architecture vs Entity Framework architecture

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to find EF Core architecture, for presentation purposes, but only find Entity Framework version like on the image below.
So, is there any difference from the point of view of architecture? In other words are these components of EF core:

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Images/ef-architecture.PNG

If no, how EF Core architecture looks like and what should be the main components?

Comment: From a developer POV: no differences. But "architecture" can mean a lot of different things, making this question too broad / opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

No. They are not. See the EF Core docs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/nuget-packages

Comment: Thank you on answer. But in that case, how looks like architecture of EF Core?

Comment: There is some info here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYhe-Mt0HzI

Answer (score 2):

> So, is there any difference from the point of view of architecture?

Yes.  EF Core is simpler than old EF.  The Conceptual Model, Storage Model, Entity SQL, and the Entity Client have been eliminated.

This leaves only the Object Model (your classes) and Fluent and Attribute-based mapping to the database which replace EDMX.  Other than that the main components are the Change Tracker, LINQ to Entities, and Migrations (which didn't exist in old EF).